# Why can't I access to the vector heads in the second for loop?

Tags: r

I just started learning R, and I have to solve this problem:
[image: text of the problem]

I have just solved it but in a way I don't like:

```r
quarto_prob = function( ripetizioni ){
      heads=rep(NA, ripetizioni)
      for (i in 1:ripetizioni) {
          diceroll = sample(1:6, 1)
          
          for( k in 1 : diceroll){
                  heads[i] = heads[i] + ( sample(0:1, 1) == 1)
              
          }
      }
      return(heads)
  }
```

I acted in this way because in the previous version of the solution, I wrote (first version of the solution):

```r
fourth_prob = function( rip ){
  heads=rep(NA, rip)
  for (i in 1:rip) {
      diceroll = sample(1:6, 1)
      
      for( k in 1 : diceroll){
              heads[i] = heads[i] + ( sample(0:1, 1) == 1)
          
      }
  }
  return(heads)
}
```

It returned me the vector empy (or with the NA values). Can anyone help me understand why is the first version of the solution not working?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste the it in directly. Images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and run directly to reproduce the problem, are hard to read on mobile devices, may be blocked by proxies or firewalls, and can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.  For more information, please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with `heads` being all `NA`, and then you add the number of heads to it. But `NA + 1` is still `NA`:

```
> NA + 1
[1] NA
> NA + 2
[1] NA
```

You can't add a number to `NA` to make it not `NA`. This is why your results are all `NA`. Instead you could start with `heads = rep(0, ripetizioni)`, because `0 + 1` gives `1` as desired.

If you want to further improve your code, you can use the `size` argument of `sample()` better. Instead of your `k` loop, you could use `sample(0:1, size = diceroll, replace = TRUE)` to do all the coin flips at once. Maybe something like

```
heads[i] = sum(sample(0:1, size = diceroll, replace = TRUE))
```

Because this is not using `+` to modify the initial values of `heads`, this approach will work with the `NA` starting values.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about R vectorization.  Vectorization minimizes the need to use explicit loops.  Suggest you work through the very good interactive tutorial, swirl: https://swirlstats.com/students.html It nicely demonstrates the concept of vectorization.   Install the R Programming module after you install swirl.  And work through that.

Here is a vectorized solution to your problem:

```
set.seed(7) # set seed for reproducibility
n <- 1000 # numeber of trials
die_rolls <- sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE) # n die rolls
# the beatuy of vectorization is here
# the size parameter in the rbinom function will update with
# a new value of the die_roll vector for each iteration
# here the n parameter is 1000 and the die_roll vector
# has length 1000 so they match up.
result <- rbinom(n, die_rolls, 0.5)
summary(result)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   1.000   2.000   1.713   2.250   6.000
```

Comment: Of course i Will try the tutorial, thanks a lot for the advise! Another question, why do you use `<-` instead of `=` in `die_rolls <- sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE)`? Where i can learn about this?

Comment: You can use = in R but <- is the default way of assigning content to variables.  Note that == is the logical comparison, e.g. if (a == b).  Also note that = is used for assigning content inside of functions, e.g, df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])